iOS Design - Tab vs. Child Screen
Are there best iOS design practices regarding when content should have its own dedicated tab, versus when it can simply be on a child screen (with a back button to the home screen)? Are they interchangeable based on the perceived level of importance of that content?
For example, I have two content screens coming from a home feed of information ("all news," and "all events") but only room for one of them on a tab bar.
I can't seem to find rules around this anywhere.
Thanks.
